# ReactJS - Property missing in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined a type `typeA` as follows:

```
export type typeA = {attr1: string, attr2: Map<string, mixed>};
```

I have a function returning back this type as so:

```
async fun1(): Promise<typeA> {...}
```

Now, when I call this function and try accessing keys of the map, I get an error:

```
var response = await fun1();
if (response.attr2.someKey) {...}
```

> property `someKey` is missing in `Map` [1].

Since, this is a map and I'm already checking for the key's existence:

- Why do I get this error?
- How do I circumvent the flow error?

Comment: Have you checked with `response.attr2.hasOwnProperty('someKey‘)` rather than what you wrote? Try also to make a console.log to see the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get property from map, you have to use `get` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).
If you wanted to define object dictionary type instead of Map it's `{ [string]: mixed }` https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps

Answer (score 1):

Map objects don't work like that, you need to use the `get(key)` as specified in the following documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get